# Is it possible for a live excel workbook to automatically filter and copy paste new data added

Tags: excel, vba

I have a shared excel workbook that I update with call stats. Each new day is added as a new sheet. I need to find a way to automatically have it update each call center agent stats sheet with the new data added.

I have made a macro that can do it for me but doesn't automatically update when new sheets are added.

Edit: Added code, I'm trying to find a way to make this automatic whenever I add a sheet

```
Sub Reception_Onsite()

    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-4],10)"
    Range("E2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Agent"
    
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="/", Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim x As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim last As Long
    Dim sht As String
    
    sht = "Master"
    
    last = Sheets(sht).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Sheets(sht).Range("A1:L" & last)
    
    Sheets(sht).Range("E1:E" & last).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("AA1"), Unique:=True
    
    For Each x In Range([AA2], Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp))
    
    With rng
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=x.Value
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    End With
    Next x
    
    Sheets(sht).AutoFilterMode = False
    
    With Application
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    
End Sub
```

Comment: If you need to adjust your code then you should include it in your post.

Comment: I find that functions like SORT() and SORTBY() update when the4 sheet is refreshed or new data is placed in the range specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into the `Workbook.NewSheet` event - more information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.newsheet

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh as Object) 
 'Code comes here
End Sub
```

If you put this Sub into your Workbook Module, the code put inside it will be run every time a new sheet is created.

Comment: For list of all events available on the Workbook object see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook